# How do you create a repeating pattern of dates split into different parts of the day? Google Sheets

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, spreadsheet, googlesheets4

I want to create a pattern of dates along a column. But these dates need to be split into different time-parts, for example:

07/02 5:00

07/02 10:00

07/03 5:00

07/02 10:00

I am honestly completely lost... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if I follow... can you include the input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating two sequences of dates and sorting them. For example, for one set of dates with 20 elements at 10 AM:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(20,1,A2)+TIME(10,0,0))
```

[image]

Then you can create both sequences with curly bracketa and sort them:

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA({SEQUENCE(20,1,A2)+TIME(10,0,0);SEQUENCE(20,1,A2)+TIME(17,0,0)}))
```

[image]

You can change "20" with a cell reference or the difference between an initial date and a final date for example